# How can I run some code in the event that a watched folder does not exist?

Tags: mule, mule4

I have a Mule 4 flow that uses the `[File] On New or Updated File` event source. This element is configured to wait for file changes within a specific folder.

When I deploy my flow, and the deployed application does not have access to the specified folder, a log message is generated and the flow terminates. However, I'd like to add some additional processing in this case. (I'd like to log a message to an alternative event log).

I tried adding an `On Error Propagate` element to the flow, but this is not triggered when the error occurs - I think this is because the error is a [system error](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/error-handling#system_errors) rather than a [messaging error](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/error-handling#messaging_errors).

If I could add a step *before* the `On New or Updated File` element, then I could check for the existence of the folder, and execute that extra code there - but I see no way to do that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to do something that "works". I created another flow that runs on a (long) timer, which runs immediately and checks for the existence of the folder by attempting to list its contents. If that fails, then the `On Error ...` block of that flow is reached, because in this case the error is treated as a messaging error rather than a system error.

Not an ideal solution, but a solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you monitor folder which should contain none existing folder?
For exmple you want to monitor /one/two/three/abc.txt. **three** does not exist. Watch **two** for new and updated files.

Comment: That would be a slight improvement in my case the folder is on a network share, and the most likely issue is that the network share doesn't exist or is inaccessible, which would mean this approach wouldn't work :-(